# PHP DOMDocument calling getElementsByTagName on a NodeList

Tags: php, dom

I'm trying to traverse a DOM tree in PHP using DOMDocument. Initial calls to getElementById / getElementsByTagName are successful, but I'm not sure how to proceed with the resulting NodeList.

Here's an example HTML file that I'm trying to traverse.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <div id="container">
      <p> Hello </p>
   </div>
</html>
```

In Javascript I'd be able to chain DOM traversal methods like so:

```
document.getElementById('container').getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerText
// returns "Hello"
```

However in PHP trying similar ...

```
<?php

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->load('test.html');

echo $document->getElementById('content')->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(0)->nodeValue . PHP_EOL;

?>
```

... simply returns this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on a non-object in /Users/liam/foobar on line 6
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this simply not supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have an element with the id `content` -- it's called `container`.

Also, you can't call `getElementById` on any old XML document.  it needs to have "a DTD which defines an attribute to be of type ID" (from [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php)).  Telling DOMDocument that the document is HTML (as is done implicitly in the case of Javascript in a browser) is enough to be able to use the function.

Here, you should call [`DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php) instead of `load`.

Comment: Brilliant! Changing to loadHTMLFile (and correcting that stupid typo of mine) worked wonderfully.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem to me that `$document->getElementById('content')` is empty, you need to change it to `$document->getElementById('container')`.

Answer (score 0):

Try xpath: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php

```
<?php
$xpath = new DOMXPath($document);

$node = $xpath->query('//*[@id="container"]//p')->item(0);
if ($node instanceof DOMNode) {
  echo $node->nodeValue . PHP_EOL;
}
```