# combining getElementsByTagName and getElementsByClassName DOMDocument

Tags: php, domdocument, getelementsbytagname, getelementsbyclassname

i try to combining `getElementsByTagName` and `getElementsByClassName` but i got some error.

for example `<p class="castplot">some text here.</p>`

i want to get `some text here`.

here what i try.

```
$information = html_entity_decode ($value['information']);

    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML($information);

    $p1 = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p')->getElementsByClassName('castplot')->textContent;
```

error i get

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
> DOMNodeList::getElementsByClassName() in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\piratefiles\fetch_details.php:21 Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 {main} thrown in

Comment: what are you hoping to accomlish?

Comment: First off - remove the @ infront of @$dom->loadHTML. Find out what the error is then report back.

Comment: @DanielA.White i want to get `text` from tag `paragrap` with class `castplot`

Comment: @DanielA.White im edit my question, hope u understand what i want.

Comment: @jeff with or without i get same error

Comment: Try to use: `$dom->getElementsByTagName('p')->item($yourIndexGoesHere)->getAttribute('castplot');` and give a look to the documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnodelist.item.php

Comment: @BSants what do u mean by `$yourIndexGoesHere` ?

Comment: It is only an index = 0,1,2... like: `$dom->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(0)->g‌​etAttribute('castplo‌​t');`. Use `var_dump($dom)` to verify information about the DOM element.

Comment: @BSants i try it from 0-2 but showing nothing.

Comment: I think I found something similar to your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046519/php-domdocument-calling-getelementsbytagname-on-a-nodelist and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224286/php-getelementsbytagname-with-specific-attribute

Comment: I forgot to say. There is a function to get the text inside the html tags called DOMinnerHTML. Give a try: http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php#89718